# Pull Array Value matches from a SQL Database with PDO (PHP)

Tags: php, sql, arrays, pdo

I have an array of ids `$friends = array(0001, 0002, 0003, 0004)` and a database where `table_name = friends`, `column_header = fid`.  `fid` in `friends` may or may not contain one of the friend IDs.  I want to input `$friends` into the query, and return all of the present values that were both in `$friends` and in a row of `fid`.

I'm sure the `fid={array_values($friends)}` is wrong, but I don't know how to pass the WHERE portion an array of values...

```
//All DB_X's are defined in another file that is included in this actual file
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=".DB_SERVER.";dbname=".DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT fid FROM friends WHERE fid={array_values($friends)} ORDER BY fid ASC");
$stmt->execute();

$friendResults = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to make use of SQL's `IN` operator:

```
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE foo IN (val1, val2, ...)
```

You can use PHP's `implode()` function to get the desired SQL bit:

```
$values = implode(', ', array_values($friends));
$query = "SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE fid IN ({$values})";
```

The above will work if your values are numeric.  If they are strings, you'll have to modify the values before `implode()`ing:

```
$values = array_map(array_values($friends), function($value) {
    return "'{$value}'"; // Here is where you could do sanitization
});
$values = implode(', ', $values);
```

**PLEASE NOTE: You must properly sanitize the data in `$friends` to prevent SQL injection.**